# Why would I still get RestrictedError in Django when related records deleted?

Tags: django

I have the following code in a unit test:

```
        serum_sample.msruns.all().delete()
        print(f"THIS SHOULD BE 0: {serum_sample.msruns.count()}")
        serum_sample.delete()
```

I get out:

```
THIS SHOULD BE 0: 0
```

In the code, I've deleted the related records that have the RESTRICT relationship, but I still get this error:

```
django.db.models.deletion.RestrictedError: ("Cannot delete some instances of model 'Sample' because they are referenced through restricted foreign keys: 'MSRun.sample'.", {<MSRun: MS run of sample BAT-xz971 with Default by anonymous on 2021-04-29>, <MSRun: MS ...
```

The relation is:

```
class MSRun(HierCachedModel, MaintainedModel):

    ...

    sample = models.ForeignKey(
        to="DataRepo.Sample",
        on_delete=models.RESTRICT,
        related_name="msruns",
        help_text="The sample that was run on the mass spectrometer.",
    )
```

I thought that to be able to delete the sample, all I had to do was delete the MSRun records that link to it...

Why would this not be the case?

### UPDATE

I previously deleted this question because I thought I'd tracked it down, but apparently not, so I am adding some more insights/context.

My hunch was in relation to the 2 databases we have: `default` and `validation`. (The validation database exists to validate user data submissions and should not be used in the context of this test.)

I'd successfully executed the delete in the validation database explicitly, which is what made me think that maybe I had some cross database foreign keys, but it turned out that it actually worked because there existed no Sample or MSRun records in the validation database (as should be the case).  So for context, in the shell:

```
In [21]: Sample.objects.using("validation").last()

In [22]: Sample.objects.using("default").last()
Out[22]: <Sample: serum-xz971>

In [42]: MSRun.objects.using("default").all()
Out[42]: <QuerySet [<MSRun: MS run of sample BAT-xz971 with Default by Anonymous on 2021-06-03>, <MSRun: MS run of sample Br-xz971 with Default by Anonymous on 2021-06-03>, <MSRun: MS run of sample Dia-xz971 with Default by Anonymous on 2021-06-03>, <MSRun: MS run of sample H-xz971 with Default by Anonymous on 2021-06-03>, <MSRun: MS run of sample Kid-xz971 with Default by Anonymous on 2021-06-03>, <MSRun: MS run of sample Liv-xz971 with Default by Anonymous on 2021-06-03>, <MSRun: MS run of sample Lu-xz971 with Default by Anonymous on 2021-06-03>, <MSRun: MS run of sample Pc-xz971 with Default by Anonymous on 2021-06-03>, <MSRun: MS run of sample Q-xz971 with Default by Anonymous on 2021-06-03>, <MSRun: MS run of sample SI-xz971 with Default by Anonymous on 2021-06-03>, <MSRun: MS run of sample Sol-xz971 with Default by Anonymous on 2021-06-03>, <MSRun: MS run of sample Sp-xz971 with Default by Anonymous on 2021-06-03>, <MSRun: MS run of sample gWAT-xz971 with Default by Anonymous on 2021-06-03>, <MSRun: MS run of sample gas-xz971 with Default by Anonymous on 2021-06-03>]>

In [43]: MSRun.objects.using("validation").all()
Out[43]: <QuerySet []>
```

The other thing is the parent classes: `HierCachedModel` and `MaintainedModel`.  The tests worked under `HierCachedModel`, and they were working on my previous branch that added `MaintainedModel`.  But in my current branch, I added the ability to propagate changes to maintained fields in related child models.  Previously, it only propagated changes to parent model records (without issue).

I am now assuming that something is awry with the propagation of child model objects, which occur in a DFS order.

Both HierChachedModel and MaintainedModel override `.delete()`:

```
class MaintainedModel(Model):

    ...

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        propagate = kwargs.pop("propagate", True)

        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)

        if auto_updates is False:
            self.buffer_parent_update()
            return

        if propagate:
            self.call_dfs_related_updaters()

class HierCachedModel(Model):

    ...

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if caching_updates:
            self.delete_related_caches()
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

I have tried calling delete with `propagate=False` -> same exception.

The propagation of updates simply calls `save()` on all referenced model objects via foreign keys, following the hierarchy.  But nowhere in that code is delete() called, so I am confounded as to why the exception mentions all those MSRun records that link to different samples other than the one I'm deleting (`serum-xz971`).

Similarly, with `HierCachedModel`, it deletes caches along the hierarchy from the root down the hierarchical tree.

Comment: I previously deleted this question because I thought I'd figured it out, but I had not. Editing now to add some of my hunches. I will comment when done.

Comment: Done.

When I tried changing `RESTRICT` to `CASCADE`, I got a different error from MaintainedModel when it tried to propagate an update to a field in a parent model object: `Animal.last_serum_sample` (which it should do, because I'm deleting a serum sample - so it should change the Animal field to the next to last serum sample). But that method tries to get the current value, which yields `Sample matching query does not exist.`. I added a catch to that exception and everything worked. But then I tried changing back to `RESTRICT` and I still get the `RestrictedError`.

Comment: New clue (commenting for myself to review later bec my laptop's battery is dead). When I set the value to CASCADE and do AnimalRec.last_serum_sample.delete(), the related records in the AnimalLabel model are deleted too. That shouldn't happen, so the delete is deleting more than it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I figured it out, though I still cannot explain the content of the error message.  Of course, I hadn't supplied enough information for anyone else to be able to answer the question, because I couldn't determine the source of the problem.  It turned out to be 2 foreign keys between the Animal and Sample tables:

```
class Animal(MaintainedModel, HierCachedModel, ElementLabel):

    ...

    last_serum_sample = models.ForeignKey(
        to="DataRepo.Sample",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="animals",
    )

class Sample(MaintainedModel, HierCachedModel):

    ...

    animal = models.ForeignKey(
        to="DataRepo.Animal",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        related_name="samples",
    )

class MSRun(HierCachedModel, MaintainedModel):

    ...

    sample = models.ForeignKey(
        to="DataRepo.Sample",
        on_delete=models.RESTRICT,
        related_name="msruns",
    )
```

Previously, `Animal.last_serum_sample` was a `@cached_function`/`@property`, but in my current branch, I changed it into a `@maintained_field_function` named `_last_serum_sample()` that spits out a value to update the new model field `last_serum_sample` which, when the record's (or a hierarchically related record's) `.save()` or `.delete` was called, it would use the output of ``.  `Animal.save()` is called to update the new `_last_serum_sample()` to update `last_serum_sample`.  But it's old value was the sample that was deleted.  So there were 2 things going on:

1. During the update, it was trying to get a sample that was in the process of being deleted, which caused an exception.
2. The delete of the sample record ultimately fails because there are 2 links to the record that were trying to govern how it is supposed to delete (MSRun.sample was set to RESTRICT and Animal.last_serum_sample was set to CASCADE).  And one was doing a save during the other's delete operation.

So, I changed `Animal.last_serum_sample.on_delete` to `SET_NULL` instead of `CASCADE`:

```
class Animal(MaintainedModel, HierCachedModel, ElementLabel):

    ...

    last_serum_sample = models.ForeignKey(
        to="DataRepo.Sample",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="animals",
    )
```

and now my test passes.

I also added a catch of the exception when the deleted record's foreign key was attempted to be accessed.

I'm still in the debug process, so I might have more to resolve, but I was quite pleased to have figured out the contention.

Now, I'm left wondering why the problem presented as a RestrictedError that referenced links to that sample record from MSRun records that are in no way related to that sample and/or animal (the relationships are hierarchical: `Animal->Sample->MSRun`).

Regardless, it seem that triggering autoupdates of related records can run afoul when multiple different model records have conflicting on_delete behaviors.

Comment: It also seems to have resolved issues with `MSRun.sample.on_delete=CASCADE` resulting in the apparent deletion of records from the `AnimalLabel` table.